# how to check internet connection on button tap in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to check for an internet connection once the login button is tapped but so far when the button is tapped, the app doesnt go through the next page but it also doesnt display the alert box. how to do it in ionic/angularjs? here's my code:

```
 if (navigator.onLine) {
    userFactory.getUser(usern).then(function(response) 
    {
        if(JSON.stringify(response.data) === "null")
        {
            alert('Please sign-up for an account.');
        }
        else
        {
            if(pass === response.data.Password)
            {

                var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                    template: '<input type="password" ng-model="userdata.passwordChange">',
                    title: 'Change Password',
                    scope: $scope,
                    buttons: [
                    { text: 'Ok' },
                    {
                        text:'Cancel',
                        type: 'button-positive',
                        onTap: function(e)
                        {
                            if(e == true)
                            {
                                myPopup.close();
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                $location.path('/page17');
                                console.log($location.path());
                                myPopup.close();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    ]
                });
            }
            else
            {
                if(pass == $scope.userdata.passwordChange)
                {
                    $location.path('/page9');
                }
                else if(pass == "omar_1992!")
                {
                    $location.path('/page9');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Login failed. Please check your credentials.');
                }

            }
        }

    });
}else{
    alert('no internet connection');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a factory that would handle all connectivity issue. Install cordova netwrok plugin to get more data like GPS, WiFi, to handle device and browser connectivity separately

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information

Include this factory in your controller and call **ConnectivityMonitor.isOnline()** to check if the user is connected to internet.

or Use  **ConnectivityMonitor.startWatching()** to monitor the connectivity

```
app.factory('ConnectivityMonitor', function($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork){
  var noInternetPopUp; 
  return {
    isOnline: function(){
      if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){
        return $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();    
      } else {
        return navigator.onLine;
      }
    },
    ifOffline: function(){
      if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){
        return !$cordovaNetwork.isOnline();    
      } else {
        return !navigator.onLine;
      }
    },
    startWatching: function(){
        if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){

          $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){

            alert('Network Change : Online');
          });

          $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){

             alert('Network Change : Offline');
          });

        }
        else {

          window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {

             alert('Network Change : Online');
          }, false);    

          window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
                 alert('Network Change : Offline');
          }, false);  
        }       
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function

```
$scope.checkInternetConnection=function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if(window.Connection) {
                if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
                    $ionicPopup.confirm({
                        title: "Internet Disconnected",
                        content: "The internet is disconnected on your device."
                    })
                    .then(function(result) {
                        if(!result) {
                            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```